# Images showing up as background but not as img src

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

This is my first post so please bear with me.

I am working on a WordPress site and came across a problem with my images.

I have a background image in my stylesheet

`background-image: "images/dummybg.jpg"`
 and that works just fine and shows up

When i go to the index file and try 

`<img src="images/dummybg.jpg">`

the image does not show up.

Both the .css and index.php are loose in my folder so their relative paths SHOULD be the same. So my question is, why would one path work and not the other?

Comment: Because your image name not correct. **dummyby.jpg**  and **dummybg.jpg**

Comment: `dummyby` vs. `dummybg`, typo here or in your HTML/CSS file?

Comment: that was a typo on my part. they are the same

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Open up the console in the browser and see if if you get any missing image errors

Comment: because the reference from your CSS may mai be the same refernce from your HTML (when css is in a subfolder for example)

Comment: the css is not in a subfolder. it is in the same folder as the index. so their file path should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress has a function to get to your image directory
So from your index it would be:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dummybg.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you used image in css. it's  automatic get image path.

but if you used in any other file in  tag you have must need put whole image path in src attribute.

you need to put current theme path in bellow wordpress function you will get.

get_template_directory();

if you need more details please visit 
 [wordpress functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)

I am sure it's work for you.